# Example of a Type that would need custom exensibility in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres there are two different flavors of a custom type:

- [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html), which is more or less just a named STRUCT in SQL, for example:

  ```
  CREATE TYPE bug_status AS ENUM ('new', 'open', 'closed');

  CREATE TABLE bug (
    id serial,
    description text,
    status bug_status
  ```

  );```
- A lower-level [`User-Defined Type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xtypes.html), defined in C with full custumizability.

What would be an example of a type that would need to be implemented at a lower-level that just having a named struct? The only examples I can find in the documentation are pretty trivial ("Box" or "Complex Number") and so would never actually require using a lower-level type, but I imagine there are other types (Geo?) that would need 100% customizability.

What would be a few examples of a type that could not be supported with a named struct?

Comment: As Alan Turing and Alonzo Church famously proved, an astonishingly wide range of tasks *can* be implemented with an astonishingly simple set of primitives; and our modern computers largely rely on that fact. So it seems somewhat missing the point to look for something that *requires* a different implementation, rather than something that *benefits from* a different implementation.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree, thanks for pointing that out! What would you say then would be a type that benefits quite a bit from a lower-level implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Many things *can* be represented as a composite type, but then input and output of your type relies on the type input and output functions of the data types used, which may not be what you want. You might want your `complex` data type to be displayed as `(-2 + 5i)`.

Also, and perhaps more importantly, the performance of data type that was implemented in C will be superior. A `complex` data type whose operators `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` are defined as PL/pgSQL functions will not be useful for number crunching.

For other examples, look at the contrib modules described in [appendix F](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html) of the documentation. I doubt that you can reasonably implement something like `ltree` as a composite type.

Comment: right, but the complex number is pretty trivial aside from display if doing arithmetic. What about other types that would be almost impossible to properly implement with an aliased-struct type?

Comment: I added another example.

Comment: awesome, thank you -- would you want to add a link to the documentation for the Appendix F for other readers as well so they don't have to google ?